# CMB2 Image link not changed when server changed

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I use CMB2 for metabox on wordpress. When I use file_list or file for media upload in CMB2. I am working a self setup local server.When I upload wordpress site on another server image link are not automatically changed. so that its takes so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to know how you move local to live server. Did you replaced old URL to new URL? You can use [Duplicator WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) for move WP site. Also you can replace manually on SQL file. You can use [this](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool too.

Comment: I upload files one server to another server. without this replace tool can i do it by any functions?

Comment: file_list can be possible by using function like this: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#file_list

Comment: yeah i know that. you dont understand my question. I face problem on directory location.